# How to view images in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django 1.7 to upload images and view them on a template. For some reason, the images that I have uploaded are not being shown. I have verified that they are uploaded and the path is saved on the database. But when retrieving it from the template, I get nothing. I have the following code:

**models.py**

```
...
class Pet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(_("Description"), default='')
    ....
class PetImage(models.Model):
    pet = models.ForeignKey(Pet, related_name='images')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="pet_images", null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Pet, PetImage

class PetForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ('title', 'description',)       

PetImageFormset = inlineformset_factory(Pet, PetImage, fields=('image',), can_delete=False, extra=3)
```

**views.py**

```
...
def new_pet(request):
    form = PetForm()
    img_formset = PetImageFormset(instance=Pet())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PetForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pet = form.save(commit=True)
            img_formset = PetImageFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=pet)
            if img_formset.is_valid():                
                img_formset.save()
                return redirect(pet)

    return render(request, "pets/new_pet.html", {
        'form': form, 
        'img_formset': img_formset,
        'action': "Create" 
    })

def view_pet(request, pet_slug, pet_id):
    pet = get_object_or_404(Pet, pk=pet_id)
    return render(request, 'pets/view_pet.html', {'pet': pet})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'apps.pets.views.all_pets', name='all_pets'),
    url(r'^(?P<pet_slug>[-\w\d]+),(?P<pet_id>\d+)/$', 'apps.pets.views.view_pet', name='view_pet'),
    url(r'^new$', 'apps.pets.views.new_pet', name='new_pet'),
)
```

How can I view the images related to a pet on the template? This is what I've tried so far but the image is not shown:

**view_pet.html**

```
<ul class="slides">                                     
    {% for photo in pet.petimage_set.all %}
        <li><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ photo.image }}" /> </li>
    {% endfor %}    
</ul>
```

Comment: From the code you've pasted, `photo.image` wouldn't do anything. Are you trying to get the corresponding `PetImage` model for the `Pet` model in the loop and *then* display that model's `image` field?

Comment: Yes @Celeo , that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `PetImage` model's `related_name` for the `Pet` foreign key is "images", change the loop to

```
{% for photo in pet.images.all %}
```

[Documentation on `related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. In addition, I had forgotten to update my urls.py to serve `/media/` content.